# Dataframe row by row to multiple scatters in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found many similar questions but never the exact issue that I'm facing.
I have a dataframe with 251 rows and 48 columns. Column 0 is the index for all other columns and represents the time data.
Each other column has a data point between 0 and 100 thats evolves over time.
I wish to create a scatter plot with the time information on x-axis and each column as separate scatter plot on y-axis. I'd like to get data from column 1 on the y-axis value 1 and depict the data values (0 to 100) by a color range of the marker.
So far I have tried to only plot the column data on separate y-levels, however I only get an empty figure without any datapoints.

Can anyone help on how to iterate through each column and on how to plot them into one scatter plot as described above?

```
print(complete)
for x, col in enumerate(complete.columns):
   for y, ind in enumerate(complete.index):
      if complete.loc[ind,col]:
         plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The dataframe "complete" looks like this:

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   ...  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46   47
0     0.0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.0
1     0.2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.0
2     0.4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.0
3     0.6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0.0
4     0.8   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1  ...   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1  0.0
..    ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ...
246  49.2   5   7   1   4   2   3   3  12  ...   0   6   2   0   3   5   0   4  1.0
247  49.4   4   7   1   4   2   2   4  12  ...   0   6   1   0   3   5   0   4  1.0
248  49.6   3   8   1   3   2   3   4  13  ...   0   7   1   0   3   5   0   5  1.0
249  49.8   4   7   1   5   3   3   3  12  ...   0   7   1   0   3   5   0   4  1.0
250  50.0   4   8   1   7   2   3   4  12  ...   0   8   1   1   3   7   0   3  0.0

[251 rows x 48 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to get data from column 1 on the y-axis value 1 and depict the data values (0 to 100) by a color range of the marker.

To be honest, I am not quite getting this as your code seems like you want to have individual plots anyways.

I suggest looking into long/tidy format dataframes, this is the way most plotting libraries expect the data to be in.
You can transform your wide format dataframe into long format by melting it ([pd.DataFrame.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html))

See the following snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generating some data
n = 251
data = {"time": np.linspace(start=0, stop=50, num=n)}
for key in range(1, 10):
    data[key] = np.random.normal(loc=key, size=n)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Melting df from wide format into long format
df = df.melt(id_vars=["time"], var_name="column")

# Individual plots per "column"
for _, col_group in df.groupby("column"):
    sns.relplot(x="time", y="value", data=col_group)
    plt.show()

# If you want to have all plots in one figure
# that is super easy with the long format
sns.relplot(x="time", y="value", data=df, col="column", col_wrap=3)
plt.show()
```

This yields plots like this one for all columns:
[image: First column]

And one like this that takes plots of all columns into a single figure:
[image: All in one]